# Auto reload div using Jquery (not reload file .php)

Tags: jquery

I'm using this code to click to reload div. "div1-wrapper" , Can you help edit it. I want it auto reload in 5 second without click.
Thanks you.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
    <script> 
        $(document).ready(function() 
        { 
        $('#simple-post').on('click', function() { 
            var url = '#';  
            $('.div1-wrapper').load(url + ' .div1'); 
         }); 
        }); 
    </script> 


    </head> 
    <body> 
        <br /> 
    <div class="div1-wrapper"> 
        <div class="div1">    
            <?php echo rand(10,100); ?> 
        </div> 
     </div>
```

Comment: You can use `setInterval(function(){ //do something}, 5000);`

Comment: You can't re-run the php inside of the div without calling the PHP again.

Comment: @RakeshKumar You mean `setTimeout()` ! Because otherwise it would fire every 5 seconds.

Comment: setTimeout run only once if requirement fulfill with this use it

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    (function($){
        $(function(){
            setInterval(function() {
                var url = '#';  
                $('.div1-wrapper').load(url + ' .div1'); 
            }, 5000);
        }); 
     })(jQuery);
    </script>
</head> 
<body> 
    <br /> 
<div class="div1-wrapper"> 
    <div class="div1">    
        <?php echo rand(10,100); ?> 
    </div> 
 </div>
```

Comment: Like Bram Driesen mentioned above, He is asking for a call after 5 seconds. So I think he needs setTimeout() instead of setInterval().

Comment: I think he wants to keep repeating it though.    Do you want to keep repeating it every 5 seconds @trung jimmy?

Comment: it work perfect , thanks you for help. <3. Can u give your facebook for make friend :D :D

Comment: Can you click the Checkmark next to my answer to accept it?   And click the up arrow too :)

Comment: Sorry,  Notorious Pet0, thought the "$(function(){" was a second onload event and therefore not needed.

Comment: no probs dude,   it's a container to alias jquery locally so the $ scope doesn't conflict

Comment: i'm come form vietnam. My english is bad:D thanks you for help. it work perfect for me.